# rosbag file cannot be made // .bag.active

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, guys!
When I was using the rosbag tool to record the real data for our robot, I used the command :
rosbag record -a
when the whole mission was accomplished, there was no .bag file made in that folder. Instead, there was a .bag.active file was made in that folder. However, when I want to replay the data, the "rosbag play " command cannot read the .bag.active file, which made it impossible to analysis the data. I cannot find a proper answer from the pages, so I hope you guys can help me.
THX

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40116/rosbag-file-cannot-be-made-//-.bag.active/) by [allelujah-wang](https://answers.ros.org/users/2945/allelujah-wang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2012-07-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allelujah-wang](https://answers.ros.org/users/2945/allelujah-wang/) on 2012-07-29**:
The .bag.active file is big, about 3.5GB each round. I started the rosbag at the very beginning. @ Lorenz

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-30**:
And how did you stop it? Just by pressing Ctrl-C and waiting or by killing it (e.g. Ctrl-, or closing the window)?

**Comment by [namanskumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/28040/namanskumar/) on 2016-09-22**:
I have the same issue. The mistake committed was that I closed the bag file using Ctrl+Z, instead of closing the bag file using Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess the rosbag process didn't shut down cleanly at the end. After recording, it might need to write an index so it must shut down cleanly.

How did you start rosbag? If you were using roslaunch and the bag file is big, it might happen that roslaunch kills rosbag after 10 seconds.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2020-02-07**:
Why is this answer accepted? It does not answer the question!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may need to use rosbag fix or rosbag reindex to fix the bagfile if it shutdown while recording.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-09-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If a bag was not closed cleanly, then the index information may be corrupted. Two steps are needed to repair the bag:

$ rosbag reindex *.bag.active

$ rosbag fix *.bag.active repaired.bag

http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#reindex

---

Originally posted by [Roger Yau](https://answers.ros.org/users/25015/roger-yau/) with karma: 211 on 2015-11-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 21

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [namanskumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/28040/namanskumar/) on 2016-09-22**:
I tried repairing the bag as suggested and converted it to txt file using the following command

```
      rostopic echo –b file.bag /rostopic> filename2.txt
```

The filename2.txt file is empty without any data inside it.

Found repaired.bag is not having any data inside it.

**Comment by [jiashiwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/26780/jiashiwei/) on 2017-03-24**:
thanks, it really work!

**Comment by [cesarhcq](https://answers.ros.org/users/40890/cesarhcq/) on 2019-06-30**:
Thanks, its worked for me!